# Unable to save choice changes to a list item after converting comments column from rich to plain text

Tags: custom-form

Background:
I have a SharePoint 2010 list where users can edit items via an edit form: they can leave a free-text comment in comments fields (text columns) and change the status of a list item by selecting a status text from a drop-down list (choice column). I update the list once week erasing all items and pasting new items  in a datasheet view from Excel.  [image: List Item Edit Form]

Bug:
The text columns initially had multiple lines of rich text format. As soon as I converted the columns format to multiple lines of **plain text**, users started having **problems saving their status choice** selected from the drop-down list. They would select a new status, click "Save" button and the edit form would close but the list item status would remain unchanged. The issue disappears as soon as one of the text fields is edited before saving the item (inserting any character would do the job). It only happens when users edit list items via an edit form. Status can be updated fine in the datasheet mode. If text column format is changed back from plain to rich text the issue disappears completely.

I wonder if anyone has encountered this behavior and found a solution. 
Thank you!